# How do I not let a user be able to modify data of another user, using django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-users

I am using django-rest-framework and generic views to build an API for a simple blog app.
I am using the RetrieveUpdateAPIView for updating data.
By default, if I have a post made by user 1, user 2 can send a POST request and be able to modify the data of the post. I do not want this to happen. This is what I have tried:

```
class PostUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        if self.request.user == self.request.POST.get('user'):
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

But this does not work. It does not let another user update the post, but it does not let the same user update the post either. I am a complete beginner so I don't really know how to query properly yet. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Your Post model probably got a "user" attribute, check if request.user is post.user. if you want to work with a queryset filter first `queryset = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. You want only the user who created the post to be able to modify it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if User 1 creates an object and User 2 want to change the content of an object related to user 1, is called PULL request and not POST. So, if u want to restrict USERS to change each other contents, you can override the update() method at 'PostSerializer'.
You can do smth like this:

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
       user_id = self.request.user_id 
       if instance.user_id != user_id:
             # Raise any exceptions
```

Comment: I implemented this but it did not work. I was still able to modify an object of user 2 as user 1. What can be going wrong?

Comment: Put a breakpoint to debug 'def update' because it seems it never Raise the exception you have wrote